# Generalized version of gradient and laplaican in spehreical coordinate for $R^D$

Tags: vector-analysis

What i want to know in this question is write generalized version of gradient in spherical coordinates for $R^D$.

I know for $3D$ case, 
\begin{align}
\nabla_{R^3} = \partial_r + \frac{1}{r^2} \nabla_{S^2}
\end{align}
where $S^2$ describes a unit sphere described by two angle variables $(\theta, \varphi)$, thus $\nabla_{S^2} = \sin^2(\theta)d\varphi^2 + d\theta^2$

How about $R^D$? can i generalized this to 
\begin{align}
\nabla_{R^D} = \partial_r + \frac{1}{r^{D-1}} \nabla_{S^{D-1}}
\end{align}
?

---

Take further i want to know the laplacian in terms of $\nabla_{S^2}$ in $3d$ case and its generalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above generalization is wrong!.$ r^2$ is fixed.

Consider 2d case 
\begin{align}
\nabla_{R^2} f = \frac{ \partial f}{\partial r} e_r + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} e_\theta 
 = \frac{ \partial f}{\partial r} \hat{e}_r + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \hat{e}_\theta 
=\frac{ \partial f}{\partial r} \hat{e}_r  + \frac{1}{r^2} \nabla_{S^1}f
\end{align}
Now for 3d case 
\begin{align}
\nabla_{R^3} f&= \frac{ \partial f}{\partial r} e_r + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} e_\theta + \frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} e_{\phi} \\
&= \frac{ \partial f}{\partial r} \hat{e}_r + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \hat{e}_\theta + \frac{1}{r^2\sin^2(\theta)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} \hat{e}_{\phi} \\
& = \frac{ \partial f}{\partial r} \hat{e}_r + \frac{1}{r^2} \nabla_{S^2} f
\end{align}
In this way i can generalized to N dimension case 
\begin{align}
\nabla_{R^N}f=\frac{ \partial f}{\partial r} \hat{e}_r + \frac{1}{r^2} \nabla_{S^{N-1}}f
\end{align}
And the laplacian can be written as 
\begin{align}
\Delta_{R^N} f = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2} + \frac{N-1}{r} \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2} \Delta_{S^{N-1}} f
\end{align}